# Intuition behind product rule of probability

Tags: probability

I have an intuitive understanding of the definition of conditional probability: $$P(x \vert y) = \frac{P(x, y)}{P(y)}$$ based on a Venn diagram. I imagine that given $y$, we zoom in on this region to make it our entire space, then select the probability of $x$.

What's an intuitive reasoning behind the product rule? I realize it is just a rearrangement of conditional probability but it doesn't make immediate sense to me: 
$$ P(y) P(x \vert y) = P(x, y)$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas Typo mistake and fixed, thank you. The spirit of the original question still stands.

Comment: If $8\%$ of students in the university study mathematics, and $75\%$ of math students like dancing, then $6\%$ of students study mathematics and like dancing. Of course $Y$ is the event "studies mathematics" and $X$ is "likes dancing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want both $x$ and $y$. What if I already have $y$,  what is the probability that I also have $x$? And then since you assumed you had $y$, you want to multiply by its probability.

Say I roll a dice, and $x$ is getting an even number, $y$ is getting $4,5$ or $6$. I want the probability of having $x$ and $y$, namely having $4$ or $6$. I first suppose that I have gotten $4,5$ or $6$. Then $P(x|y)=2/3$. This is valid IF I get $4,5$ or $6$, which happens with probability $1/2$.

The idea is to try to simplify a probability by assuming a portion of the randomness. When you multiply by $P(y)$ (in this example), you  remove that assumption bringing back all the randomness that was present.